# Smarty loop over nested array

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

Hello I want to print the data of a nested array, this is my array: $result[]

the result array is build like this

```
foreach($pictureIds as $pressId) {
    $picture = PressPicture::_getItemByPressId($pressId);
    $result['picture'][] = $picture;
    $pressItem = PressItem::_fromNumber($pressId);

    if($pressItem) {
        $result['title'][] = $pressItem->getTitle();
    }
}

Array
    (
    [picture] => Array
        (
            [0] => PressPicture Object
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [press_id] => 3
                            [update_time] => 1331738139
                            [ord] => 1
                        )

                    [dataLang] => 
                    [prettyClassName] => 
                )

            [1] => PressPicture Object
                (
                    [id] => 31
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                            [press_id] => 4
                            [update_time] => 1332144196
                            [ord] => 1
                        )

                    [dataLang] => 
                    [prettyClassName] => 
                )

        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tetsij
            [1] => Persbericht
        )
)
```

How is it possible to loop over this array. So I have my title , and then my picture. I tried this

```
{foreach name=outer item=it from=$result}
<li>
    {foreach from=$it item=value key=key}
      {assign var=item value=$value}
      <img src="{$item->getPictureUrl('list', 180, 120, true, false, true)}" alt="{$item->getTitle()}" width="180" height="120" />
     {/foreach}
</li>
{/foreach}
```

I can work with the object but how is it possible to print the title that also is in the array?

Comment: how's your current output look like?

Comment: My current output gives me a picture because I can reach the picture object. But what I want is my picture + the title that also is in my $result[] array.

Comment: Did you mention to add the title property to your PressPicture-Class? It seems that every picture can have a title so it is a cleaner way to store the title within the object. In result you don't have 2 arrays with data to loop, you only have one and you can access the title via a get-Method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the key argument from the picture foreach as index to access the title array.

```
{foreach name=outer item=pictures from=$result.picture}
<li>
    {foreach from=$pictures item=pic key=key}
        <img src="{$pic->getPictureUrl('list', 180, 120, true, false, true)}" alt="{$result.title[$key]}" width="180" height="120" />
    {/foreach}
</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , when write the foreach this way: I get an 
error:Fatal error: Call to a member function getPictureUrl() on a non-object in..

Comment: I don't know which methods your PressPicture Object implements :-)